# accessing multiple files using argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to read number of files using `argparse`:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '-f',
    '--text-file',
    metavar='IN FILE',
    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
    nargs='*')
...
...
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

when more than one files are passed as command line arguments, only last file appears into args:

```
python example.py -o x.xml -s sss -c ccc -t "hello world" --report_failure -f ex.1  -f ex.2
Namespace(outputfile=<open file 'x.xml', mode 'w' at 0x028AD4F0>, report_failure=True, test_case='ccc', test_suite='sss', text='hello world', text_file=[<open file 'ex.2', mode 'r' at 0x028AD5A0>])
```

What I did wrong and how to access all files I passed from the command line?
Note: I'm using python 2.7.6 on Windows.

Comment: You have to use `action='append'` instead of `nargs='*'` to handle that command line.  Both create lists, but in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complication occurs because you're passing multiple arguments to the same parameter -f and each argument replaces the argument before it. What would work in this case is:

```
python example.py -o x.xml -s sss -c ccc -t "hello world"
--report_failure -f ex.1 ex.2
```

This will collect ex.1 and ex.2 into a list, which is what I assume you want to do.

as a reference here is the docs on nargs:

> '*'. All command-line arguments present are gathered into a list. Note
>   that it generally doesn’t make much sense to have more than one
>   positional argument with nargs='*', but multiple optional arguments
>   with nargs='*' is possible.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs